# Error when trying to transform sales order to itemFulfillment [REST API]

Tags: netsuite

I'm new to NetSuite development and am encountering the following issue. I want to transform a sales order to an itemFulfillment using the rest endpoint .../salesorder/{id}/!transform/itemfulfillment but I'm running into errors.

I've followed the documentation using the json body

```
{
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "item": {
                    "id": "123"
                },
                "orderLine": 1,
                "quantity": 1,
                "itemReceive": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

however I get the following error response
{
"type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.1",
"title": "Bad Request",
"status": 400,
"o:errorDetails": [
{
"detail": "Error while accessing a resource. You must have at least one valid line item for this transaction.",
"o:errorCode": "USER_ERROR"
}
]
}

I've tried adding more fields to the json body but still get the same error. The item I'm trying to fulfill is a non inventory item. Does anybody know what the inherent issue is or have experience with using this endpoint. Any help would be greatly appreciated.